# Как сделать отдельное окошко

Tags: java, android

В приложении 2 EditText , при нажатии на 1 EditText , открывается так сказать фокус и при нажатии на кнопку готово переходит на новую активность.
При нажатии на 2 EditText, я просто ввожу цифры и при нажатии на кнопку готово не открывается новая активности т.к 1 EditText не заполнен.
Как сделать 2 независимую от другой.
Код xml: http://pastebin.com/8RNjpguX

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

mDone.setOnClickListener(e -> {

```
        //TODO Сделать оплату

        if (mVinEdit.hasFocus() || mVinEdit.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            int length = mVinEdit.getText().length();

            if (numbersOff(length) == false) {

                mVinEdit.setError(getString(R.string.fail_vin));

            } else if(numbersOff(length) == true) {

                intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, VinCheckActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.vin_data_tag), mVinEdit.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);

              //there need translate token  intent
            }

        } else if (mPhoneEdit.hasFocus() || mPhoneEdit.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            int length = mPhoneEdit.getText().length();
            if (length != 10) {

                mPhoneEdit.setError(getString(R.string.fail_phone));
            } else {

                intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, PhoneCheckActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.phone_tag), "7" + mPhoneEdit.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

        clear();

        hideSoftKeyboard();

    });
}
```

Comment: Что значит независимой от другой?Они в принципе не зависимы, две разные активити.

Comment: @Asgard я привел вам скриншоты, вы видите, что при нажатии на 1 Едит , вторая скрывается, а при нажатии на 2 она не скрывается.

Comment: вы через `intent` переходите на другую активити, верно?У другой активити та разметка, которую укажете вы. Мне не понятно в чем проблема. Если не хватает `EditText` - добавьте в XML второй активити и нужные данные помещайте в `intent`, и вытаскивайте через `getExtras()`

Comment: @Asgard было бы прекрасно, если бы вы подсказали как вставить текст при долгом табе

Comment: @Asgard да, вы не поняли, при нажатии на 1 едит и ввода номера и при нажатии на кнопку готово он переходит на новую активность.

При нажатии на 2 едит  и нажатии на кнопку готово , он не переходит на новую активность, а все почему? Потому что 1 едит не скрывается.

Comment: давайте лучше разметку и код с переходами, по руке гадаю только по четвергам)

Comment: @Asgard обновил